# CMake : No output of the building process

Tags: c++, cmake, webkit, webkitgtk

With this `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  WebKit2
  #URL https://webkitgtk.org/releases/webkitgtk-2.42.3.tar.xz
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/raphael10-collab/webkitgtkIncludable.git
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(webkit2)
add_executable(my_application src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(my_application PRIVATE $webkit2:$webkit2)
```

I not get errors but I do not get also any output :

```
cmake -B build
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done (5.0s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/raphy/slint/cpp-base-slint/build
```

No output of the building process :

```
raphy@raohy:~/slint/cpp-base-slint/build/_deps$ ls -lah
total 20K
drwxrwxr-x 5 raphy raphy 4,0K dic 17 13:12 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 raphy raphy 4,0K dic 17 13:12 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 raphy raphy 4,0K dic 17 13:12 webkit2-build
drwxrwxr-x 3 raphy raphy 4,0K dic 17 13:12 webkit2-src
drwxrwxr-x 4 raphy raphy 4,0K dic 17 13:12 webkit2-subbuild
raphy@raohy:~/slint/cpp-base-slint/build/_deps$ 

raphy@raohy:~/slint/cpp-base-slint/build/_deps/webkit2-src$ ls -lah
total 31M
drwxrwxr-x 3 raphy raphy 4,0K dic 17 13:12 .
drwxrwxr-x 5 raphy raphy 4,0K dic 17 13:12 ..
drwxrwxr-x 8 raphy raphy 4,0K dic 17 13:12 .git
-rw-rw-r-- 1 raphy raphy  31M dic 17 13:12 webkitgtk-2.42.3.tar.xz

raphy@raohy:~/slint/cpp-base-slint/build/_deps/webkit2-subbuild$ ls -lah
total 40K
drwxrwxr-x 4 raphy raphy 4,0K dic 17 13:12 .
drwxrwxr-x 5 raphy raphy 4,0K dic 17 13:12 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 raphy raphy 4,5K dic 17 13:12 CMakeCache.txt
drwxrwxr-x 5 raphy raphy 4,0K dic 17 13:12 CMakeFiles
-rw-rw-r-- 1 raphy raphy 1,6K dic 17 13:12 cmake_install.cmake
-rw-r--r-- 1 raphy raphy 1,8K dic 17 13:12 CMakeLists.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 raphy raphy 4,7K dic 17 13:12 Makefile
drwxrwxr-x 4 raphy raphy 4,0K dic 17 13:12 webkit2-populate-prefix

raphy@raohy:~/slint/cpp-base-slint/build/_deps/webkit2-build$ ls -lah
total 8,0K
drwxrwxr-x 2 raphy raphy 4,0K dic 17 13:12 .
drwxrwxr-x 5 raphy raphy 4,0K dic 17 13:12 ..
```

My objective is to reproduce the WebKitGTK building phases within a CMakeLists.txt : https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/BuildingGtk#BuildingWebKitGTKfromareleasetarball

How to make it work?